# How to match and assign data the pythonic way?

Tags: mysql, match, python

I have a list (mysql table) of People and their titles as shown in the table below. I also have a list of titles and their categories. How do I assign their categories to the person? The problem arises when there are multiple titles for a person. What is the pythonic way of mapping the title to the category and assigning it to the person?

**People Table**

```
Name   Title
--------------------
John D CEO, COO, CTO 
Mary J COO, MD
Tim  C Dev Ops, Director
```

**Title Category table**

```
Title      Executive IT Other
-----------------------------
CEO        1
COO        1
CTO        1          1
MD         1
Dev Ops               1
Director                 1
```

**Desired output :**

```
Name   Title             Executive  IT  Other
---------------------------------------------
John D CEO, COO, CTO     1          1
Mary J COO, MD           1 
Tim  C Dev Ops, Director            1   1
```

Comment: It would help to see what your intended output should look like.

Comment: How are your people stored? A class, a string? This question is far too vague.

Comment: Also where is the list of titles and categories?

Comment: @ThinkCode check out my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name_title = (("John D",("CEO","COO","CTO")),
              ("Mary J",("COO","MD")),
              ("Tim C",("Dev Ops","Director")))
title_cat = {"CEO": set(["Executive"]),
             "COO": set(["Executive"]),
             "CTO": set(["Executive"]),
             "MD": set(["Executive"]),
             "Dev Ops": set(["IT"]),
             "Director": set(["Other"])}

name_cat = [(name, reduce(lambda x,y:x|y, [title_cat[title]for title in titles])) for name,titles in name_title]
```

It would be nice if there was a `union` which behaved like `sum` on sets.

Comment: A title can have 2 categories or more, in this case CTO has 2 categories, IT and Executive? This is a small sample, I have few thousand contacts! Thanks....

Comment: Yes, you can do `"CTO":set(["Executive","IT"])`

Comment: Keith, would you change anything if you have half a million contacts with titles and about 20000 different titles to map. How to scale the solution in that case? Iterators? Thank you!

Comment: @ThinkCode: I don't think so.  It should scale fine to that size.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. I will also try parallel Python just for the heck of it and see and improvements in time if at all I feel like it is taking forever.

Comment: How do I implement a try .. except? For instance say title_cat[title] doesn't validate, how do I ignore that particular title? 'if title_cat[title]' doesn't work. I tried : in [title_cat[title]for title in titles if title_cat[title]], no go. Thank you!

Comment: You probably want something like `title_cat[title] if title in title_cat else set()`.  Or use a `defaultdict` instead of a regular dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Start by arranging your input data in a dictionary-of-lists form:

```
>>> name_to_titles = {
        'John D': ['CEO', 'COO', 'CTO'],
        'Mary J': ['COO', 'MD'],
        'Tim C': ['Dev Ops', 'Director']
}
```

Then loop over the input dictionary to create the reverse mapping:

```
>>> title_to_names = {}
>>> for name, titles in name_to_titles.items():
        for title in titles:
            title_to_names.setdefault(title, []).append(name)

>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(title_to_names)
{'CEO': ['John D'],
 'COO': ['John D', 'Mary J'],
 'CTO': ['John D'],
 'Dev Ops': ['Tim C'],
 'Director': ['Tim C'],
 'MD': ['Mary J']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
people=['john','Mary','Tim']
Title=[['CEO','COO','CTO'],['COO','MD'],['DevOps','Director']]
title_des={'CEO':'Executive','COO':'Executive','CTO':'Executive',
           'MD':'Executive','DevOps':'IT','Director':'Others'
           }
people_des={}

for i,x in enumerate(people):
    people_des[x]={}
    for y in Title[i]:
        if title_des[y] not in people_des[x]:
             people_des[x][title_des[y]]=[y]
        else:     
             people_des[x][title_des[y]].append(y) 
print(people_des)
```

**output:**

```
{'Tim': {'IT': ['DevOps'], 'Others': ['Director']}, 'john': {'Executive': ['CEO', 'COO', 'CTO']}, 'Mary': {'Executive': ['COO', 'MD']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this if you mean you have the string:

```
s = '''Name   Title
--------------------
John D CEO, COO, CTO
Mary J COO, MD
Tim  C Dev Ops, Director

Title      Executive IT Other
-----------------------------
CEO        1
COO        1
CTO        1
MD         1
Dev Ops               1
Director                 1
'''

lines = s.split('\n')
it = iter(lines)

for line in it:
    if line.startswith('Name'):
        break

next(it) # '--------------------'

for line in it:
    if not line:
        break
    split = line.split()
    titles = split[2:]
    name = split[:2]
    print ' '.join(name), titles

# John D ['CEO,', 'COO,', 'CTO']
# Mary J ['COO,', 'MD']
# Tim C ['Dev', 'Ops,', 'Director']
```